# Django Test Error: "1824, Failed to open the referenced table"

Tags: mysql, django, testing, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is the flow of how my database is created:

- I already have a legacy MySql database with some tables.
- I create the django project and connect it to the legacy database.
- I run migrate, in order to create the django tables for sessions and authentication on the legacy DB.
- Then, directly from the DB I create the [GeSession Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mYru.png) and the reference to the [DjangoSession Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6uog.png).
- Then I import all the tables models using "inspectdb" command.
- To be able to test, inside models.py, I set managed = True to every table except for the django ones. Then I run makeMigrations and migrate --fake-initial.

If I try to use the django ORM to make queries it works without any problem, but during testing it keeps failing the test database creation giving me this error:

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'django_session'")

and then right after:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'django_session'")
```

Everytime I tweak something on the models.py file I delete the first migration file, I run makemigrations and then run: migrate --fake-initial.

I dont understand what I'm doing wrong. Is it bad to keep the django tables and the other ones on the same database ? Should I use multiple databases ?

I tried removing the reference from GeSession to DjangoSession and it works, the test database is created and I can test DB queries.

I tried making queries on the DjangoSession table to be sure that is being created in the test database, and they work without problems.